# mpi program in c compiles but doesnt run

Tags: c, mpi

I am a beginner in MPI programming. I am trying to execute a code in which a new matrix is formed from an old one using Anew[i][j]=Aold[i][j]+Aold[i][j+1] and this takes place for 10 times. I write the following code :

```
#include"mpi.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
void calculate();
int taskid,numtasks,numworkers,rowmean,offset,t,
BEGIN=1,
msgtype,
start,
RTAG=3,
LTAG=2,
NX=20,
NY=20,
MASTER=0,
NONE=0,
DONE=4,
TIMESTEP=10,
source,
ext,
end,
left,
rows,
right,
dest;
MPI_Status status;
float u[2][NX][NY];

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);
numworkers=numtasks-1;

rowmean=NX/numworkers;
ext=NX%numworkers;

if (taskid==MASTER)
{
    offset=0;
    for (int i=1;i<=numworkers;i++)
    {
        if (i==1)
        {
            left=NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            left=i-1;
        }
        if (i==numworkers)
        {
            right=NONE;
        }
        else
        {
            right=i+1;
        }
        dest=i;
        rows=(i<=ext) ? rowmean+1:rowmean;
        MPI_Send(&u[0][offset][0],rows*NY,MPI_FLOAT,dest,BEGIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&offset,1,MPI_INT,dest,BEGIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows,1,MPI_INT,dest,BEGIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&right,1,MPI_INT,dest,BEGIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&left,1,MPI_INT,dest,BEGIN,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        offset=offset+rows;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=numworkers;i++)
    {
        source=i;
        msgtype=DONE;
        MPI_Recv(&u[1][offset][0],rows*NY,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }   
    MPI_Finalize();
    /*end of master code*/
}
```

/************************************WORKER CODE**************************************************************/

```
if (taskid!=MASTER)
{
    /* initialization*/
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<NX;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<NY;k++)
            {
                u[i][j][k]=i+j+k;
                //cout<<u[i][j][k]<<" ";
            }
            //cout<<"\n";
        }
        //cout<<"\n\n";
    }
    source=MASTER;
    msgtype=BEGIN;
    MPI_Recv(&u[0][offset][0],rows*NY,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&offset,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&rows,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&left,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&right,1,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    int iz=0;

    for (int t=1;t<=TIMESTEP;t++)
    {
        start=offset;
        if (offset==0)
        {
            start=1;
        }
        end=offset+rows-1;
        if (end==NY-1)
        {
            end=NY-2;
        }
        if (left!=NONE)
        {
            MPI_Send(&u[iz][offset][0],NY,MPI_FLOAT,left,RTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            source=left;
            msgtype=LTAG;
            MPI_Recv(&u[iz][offset-1][0],NY,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        }
        if (right!=NONE)
        {
            MPI_Send(&u[iz][offset+rows-1][0],NY,MPI_FLOAT,right,LTAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            source=right;
            msgtype=RTAG;
            MPI_Recv(&u[iz][offset+rows][0],NY,MPI_FLOAT,source,msgtype,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        }
        iz=1-iz;
        calculate(start,end,NY,&u[iz][offset][0],&u[1-iz][offset][0]);
    }
    MPI_Send(&u[iz][offset][0],rows*NY,MPI_FLOAT,MASTER,DONE,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, DONE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize;
}
return 0;
```

}

```
/* calculate function*/
void calculate(int start,int end,int NY,float *u1, float *u2)
{
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<NY;j++)
    {
        *(u2+i*NY+j)=*(u1+i*NY+j)+*(u1+(i+1)*NY+j);
    }
}
```

}

The code compiles fine using

```
mpicc mpi_matrix.c
```

but doesn't run using

```
mpirun -n 4 mpi_matrix
```

gives the error

```
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.
```

Can Anyone help? 
Thank you

EDIT 1: after trying what @mko said. The program compiles and runs but with an error. Following is the error

```
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] *** reported by process [3817603073,3]
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in   this communicator will now abort,
[shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:3296] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Comment: gives the error "mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well."

Comment: I do not use mpi but a look at [this page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun) suggests there is no `-n` argument.

Comment: ...oops but [this page](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man1/mpirun.1.php) has it.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the contents of your program. Look into the documentation of your MPI environment how to run executables. This part of MPI is not normalized, so we can't really tell unless you also give us the name of your MPI.

Comment: Try this: mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_matrix

Comment: @JensGustedt sorry about that. I am using OpenMPI version 2.1.1.

Comment: @mko doesn't work. Getting the error "mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access
or execute an executable:

Executable: ./mpi_matrix
Node: shekhar-HP-Pavilion-Notebook

while attempting to start process rank 0.
"

Comment: OK - I didn't notice that you haven't passed -o ;) In that case, mpicc will create a.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with mpicc you need to specify **-o** to provide target file name.

Try this

```
mpicc -o mpi_matrix mpi_matrix.c
mpirun -np 4 ./mpi_matrix
```

alternatively start it like this

```
mpirun -np 4 ./a.out
```

By default, if you don't provide -o, mpicc will create **a.out** executable.

Comment: If you find it as a solution for your issue, it would be nice if you could accept it. Have fun with MPI :)

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. It works perfectly good. But now I have an issue with the code. Gives an error. (see edited question)

Comment: it seems `rows` is uninitialized if `taskid!=MASTER`